Mockito.mock() not mocking the Class in Java 17
StackOverflow Community.
Mockito.mock() is not working as expected in Java 17. The class which I can mock using Java 8 is not mocked when I upgraded the java version to Java 17.
Any idea on this?

more details please, add some code

This works for Java 17 - mock(User.class, withSettings().withoutAnnotations())
